# Know what is modified in a file in c#

Tags: c#, file

I would like to know if it is possible to be alerted when a file has been modified (FileSystemWatcher ?) and what has been modified in this file using C# ?

Thanks :)

Comment: use TFS source control.

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  You'll have to use `FileSystemWatcher` and then read an old (previous) copy of the file and the new file, and write your own compare routines.  Or, you could simply use TFS or some other source control system rather than reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

FileSystemWatcher has a changed event handler.Use that to grab the new file and then compare it to an old copy of itself(possibly through some archive folder,Storage directory).

Comment: Here's a great example :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58740/FileSystemWatcher-Pure-Chaos-Part-of